# Mock is not working properly when i try to return optional

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mockito

I'm writing a test for a method in which the repository should return a user, I've hardcoded this logic, but my mock returns an empty optional.
Here is the method code

```
@Override
public AppChatMember getByTelegramId(long telegramId) {
    return userRepository.findByTelegramId(telegramId).orElseThrow(() -> new UserNotFoundException(
            String.format(USER_NOT_FOUND_BY_TG_ID, telegramId)));
}
```

Here is the test code

```
@Test
@DisplayName("Checking that method is calling find by telegram id")
void getByTelegramIdShouldCallFindByTelegramId() {
    long expectedTelegramId = 123456L;
    AppChatMember user = getAppChatMember();

    when(userRepository.findByTelegramId(anyLong())).thenReturn(Optional.of(user));

    userService.getByTelegramId(expectedTelegramId);

    verify(userRepository, times(1)).findByTelegramId(expectedTelegramId);
}
```

Setting up mocks

```
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
class UserServiceImplTest {

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@MockBean
private UserRepository userRepository;

@MockBean
private GroupRepository groupRepository;

@Captor
private ArgumentCaptor<AppChatMember> appChatMemberCaptor;
```

Here is getAppchatMember

```
AppChatMember getAppChatMember() {
    AppChatMember user = new AppChatMember();
    user.setNickName("Nickname");
    user.setTelegramId(123456L);
    user.setIsProcessing(true);
    return user;
}
```

Here is userRepository

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends     
JpaRepository<AppChatMember, Long> {

boolean existsByTelegramId(long telegramId);

Optional<AppChatMember> findByTelegramId(long telegramId);

Optional<AppChatMember> findByTelegramId(Long telegramId);

List<AppChatMember> findByCondition(UserConditionEnum condition);
```

}

Comment: What does the `UserRepository` look like?

Comment: What does `getAppChatMember()` look like?

Comment: When debugging your test do you see the mock implementation in method `getByTelegramId(`. Also have you tried replacing `anyLong() with any()`?

Comment: @GJohannes I tried replacing it but it didn't help, the test fails with an error

Comment: @M.Deinum Add to my question

Comment: @1615903 Add to my question

Comment: Remove one of the `findByTelegramId` methods. I would keep the `Long` one as that matches the type of the id. Mockito will mock one, probably the `Long` one, whereas you are calling the `long` one. This doesn't match the matcher and does the default, return an empty optional.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you, this helped, the problem was that there were 2 identical methods, but one took a primitive, and the second was an object type and Mockito did not work correctly

Comment: Well Mockito did work correctly, it mocked the method it needed to mock (the one with a `Long` as that, technically, is what you asked it to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there were 2 identical methods, but one took a primitive, and the second was an object type and Mockito mock te object type method, so solution is delete one from repository.